# SELECT AVG por horas

Tags: sql-server

tengo una tabla la cual absorbe constantemente datos por minuto necesito crear una consulta la cual me haga la media por horas y me la muestre, ¿Cuál sería el método? gracias.

```
SELECT AVG(dato1), AVG(dato2), AVG(dato3) from tabla1 where flag ='1' and fecha <= 'xxxx-xx-xx' and fecha >= 'xxxx-xx-xx'
```

La idea es que me muestre esa consulta pero de cada hora. Gracias.

Comment: y un gorup by no funciono?

Comment: como sería un group by para mostrar la media por horas?

Comment: donde estan las horas? en que campo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas mostrar las horas y agrupar en cada una de ellas la media de cada dato y para ello tienes el `GROUP BY`. Las horas las puedes obtener de la función `DATEPART` del campo fecha, entendiendo que es un campo `DATETIME`

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour, fecha) as Hora, AVG(dato1), AVG(dato2), AVG(dato3) 
from tabla1 
where flag ='1' and fecha <= 'xxxx-xx-xx' and fecha >= 'xxxx-xx-xx' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, fecha)
ORDER BY Hora
```

Si lo que quieres es mostrar horas y minutos, puedes hacerlo con un `FORMAT`

```
SELECT FORMAT(fecha,'HH:mm') as HoraMin, AVG(dato1), AVG(dato2), AVG(dato3) 
from tabla1 
where flag ='1' and fecha <= 'xxxx-xx-xx' and fecha >= 'xxxx-xx-xx' 
GROUP BY FORMAT(fecha,'HH:mm')
ORDER BY HoraMin
```

Comment: Perdón, no estaba mal, era simplemente que no había registros en esas horas, como puedo mostrar la hora para que me muestre hh:mm y no solo hh al realizar la consulta? Gracias.

Comment: He editado la respuesta para añadir la posibilidad de mostrar la información agrupada por horas y minutos (hh:mm)